# Java EE JSR 352 - Jberet Dynamic Job Builder and Execution

Tags: java, java-ee-7, jsr352, jberet

Understood from Jberet [userguide](https://jberet.gitbooks.io/jberet-user-guide/content/programmatic_job_definition_with_java/index.html) that a job can be build dynamically as alternative to static xml, but the guide doesn't have any input on how to execute the job build, So willing to know how to execute the job.

```
Job job = new JobBuilder(jobName)
  .restartable(false)
  .property("jobk1", "J")
  .property("jobk2", "J")
  .listener("jobListener1", new String[]{"jobListenerk1", "#{jobParameters['jobListenerPropVal']}"},
          new String[]{"jobListenerk2", "#{jobParameters['jobListenerPropVal']}"})

  .step(new StepBuilder(stepName)
          .properties(new String[]{"stepk1", "S"}, new String[]{"stepk2", "S"})
          .batchlet(batchlet1Name, new String[]{"batchletk1", "B"}, new String[]{"batchletk2", "B"})
          .listener("stepListener1", stepListenerProps)
          .stopOn("STOP").restartFrom(stepName).exitStatus()
          .endOn("END").exitStatus("new status for end")
          .failOn("FAIL").exitStatus()
          .nextOn("*").to(step2Name)
          .build())

  .step(new StepBuilder(step2Name)
          .batchlet(batchlet1Name)
          .build())

          .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you use the following method to start a job created with Java JSL:

```
org.jberet.operations.AbstractJobOperator#start(org.jberet.job.model.Job, java.util.Properties)
```

**Version 1.3.0 beta**

Since Java JSL is an extra feature, you will need to obtain JBeret implementation of JobOperator and call the above start method:

```
import org.jberet.job.model.Job;
import org.jberet.operations.JobOperatorImpl;
import org.jberet.spi.JobOperatorContext;

JobOperatorImpl jobOperator = (JobOperatorImpl) JobOperatorContext.getJobOperatorContext().getJobOperator();

Job job = new JobBuilder(jobName)
                .step(new StepBuilder(stepName)
                        .reader(...)
                        .writer(...)
                        .build())
                .build();
Properties params = null;
long jobExecutionId = jobOperator.start(job, params);
```

**Version 1.2.0-Final**

```
JobOperatorImpl jobOperator = (JobOperatorImpl) BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
Properties jobProperties = new Properties();
long jobExecutionId = jobOperator.start(job, jobProperties);
```

For more details, see JBeret [sample app javaJSL](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/master/test-apps/javaJSL/src/test/java/org/jberet/testapps/javajsl/JavaJSLIT.java), and code [how to get JBeret job operator](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/master/test-apps/common/src/main/java/org/jberet/testapps/common/AbstractIT.java#L72).

Comment: thanks.. `import org.jberet.spi.JobOperatorContext;` is available in jberet-core-1.3.0-beta, but right now am using V1.2.0final, so i did `JobOperatorImpl jobOperator = (JobOperatorImpl) BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();`